# JavaScript functions not producing expected behavior

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I think I did everything right but when I click the button "Batter Up!", nothing happens. Please help me figure out what kind of things I am missing here.

Here is the code:

```js
var leftball = new Array(423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 421, 419, 418, 416, 414, 413, 411, 409, 407, 406, 404, 402, 401, 399, 397, 395, 394, 392, 390, 389, 387, 385, 383, 382, 380, 378, 377, 375, 373, 371, 370, 368, 366, 365, 363, 361, 359, 358, 356, 354, 353, 351, 349, 347, 346, 344, 342, 341, 339, 337, 335, 334, 332, 330, 329, 327, 325, 323, 322, 320, 318, 317, 315, 313, 311, 310, 308, 306, 305, 303, 301, 299, 298, 296, 294, 293, 291, 289, 287, 286, 284, 282, 281, 279, 277, 275, 274, 272, 270, 269, 267, 265, 263, 262, 260, 258, 257, 255, 253, 251, 250, 248, 246, 245, 243, 241, 239, 238, 236, 234, 233, 231, 229, 227, 226, 224, 222, 221, 219, 217, 215, 214, 212, 210, 208, 207, 205, 203, 202, 200);
var topball = new Array(365, 367, 369, 371, 373, 375, 377, 379, 381, 383, 385, 387, 389, 391, 393, 395, 397, 399, 401, 403, 405, 407, 409, 411, 413, 415, 417, 419, 421, 423, 425, 427, 429, 431, 433, 435, 437, 439, 441, 443, 445, 447, 449, 451, 453, 455, 457, 459, 461, 463, 465, 467, 469, 471, 473, 475, 477, 479, 481, 483, 485, 487, 489, 491, 493, 495, 497, 499, 501, 503, 500, 496, 492, 487, 483, 479, 475, 471, 466, 462, 458, 454, 450, 445, 441, 437, 433, 429, 425, 420, 416, 412, 408, 404, 399, 395, 391, 387, 383, 379, 374, 370, 366, 362, 358, 353, 349, 345, 341, 337, 333, 328, 324, 320, 316, 312, 307, 303, 299, 295, 291, 286, 282, 278, 274, 270, 266, 261, 257, 253, 249, 245, 240, 236, 232, 228, 224, 220, 215, 211, 207, 203, 199, 194, 190, 186, 182, 178, 173, 169, 165, 161, 157, 153, 148, 144, 140, 136, 132, 127, 123, 119, 115, 111, 107, 102, 98, 94, 90, 86, 81, 77, 73, 69, 65, 61, 56, 52, 48, 44, 40, 35, 31, 27, 23, 19, 14, 10, 6, 2, -2, -6, -11, -15, -19, -23, -27, -32, -36, -40);
var widthsize = new Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 9, 17, 25, 33, 41, 49, 57, 65, 73, 81, 89, 97, 105, 113, 121, 129, 137, 145, 153, 161, 169, 177, 185, 193, 201, 209, 217, 225, 233, 241, 249, 257, 265, 273, 281, 289, 297, 305, 313, 321, 329, 337, 345, 353, 361, 369, 377, 385, 393, 401, 409, 417, 425, 433, 441, 449, 457, 465, 473, 481, 489, 497, 505, 512, 520, 528, 536, 544, 552, 560, 568, 576, 584, 592, 600);
var heightsize = new Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 6, 9, 11, 14, 17, 19, 22, 25, 27, 30, 32, 35, 38, 40, 43, 46, 48, 51, 54, 56, 59, 62, 64, 67, 70, 72, 75, 78, 80, 83, 86, 88, 91, 94, 96, 99, 101, 104, 107, 109, 112, 115, 117, 120, 123, 125, 128, 131, 133, 136, 139, 141, 144, 147, 149, 152, 155, 157, 160, 163, 165, 168, 170, 173, 176, 178, 181, 184, 186, 189, 192, 194, 197, 200);

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var timer;
var cycle = 0;

function moveBall(a, b) {
  x = a + document.getElementById("ball").offsetLeft;
  document.getElementById("ball").style.left = x + "px";

  y = b + document.getElementById("ball").offsetTop;
  document.getElementById("ball").style.top = y + "px";
}

function sizeSign(a, b) {
  x = a + document.getElementById("homerun").offsetHeight;
  document.getElementById("homerun").style.height = x + "px";

  y = b + document.getElementById("homerun").offsetWidth;
  document.getElementById("homerun").style.width = y + "px";
}

function runIt() {
  if (cycle < 200) {
    moveBall(leftball, topball)
  } else if (cycle = 200) {
    document.getElementById("ball").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("homerun").style.visibility = "visible";
  } else if (cycle < 275) {
    sizeSign(heightsize, widthsize);
  } else if (cycle = 275) {
    clearInterval(timer);
  }
  cycle++;
}

function batterup() {
  timer = setInterval(runIt, 50);
}
//////////////////////////////END////////////////////////////////
```

```css
body {
  background-color: blue;
}

#ballfield {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  z-index: -1;
}

#ball1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 365px;
  left: 423px;
  z-index: 2;
  visibility: visible;
}

#homerun {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 150px;
  z-index: 3;
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 1px;
  width: 1px;
}

#button1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="button1" value="Batter Up!" onclick="batterup()" />
<img src="baseballfield.jpg" alt="ballfield" id="ballfield" />
<img src="baseball.gif" alt="baseball" id="ball1" />
<img src="homerun.gif" alt="home run" id="homerun" />
```

And Images:

[baseball.gif]

[baseballfield.jpg]

[homerun.gif]

https://www.dropbox.com/s/idnjd49p2iuo3wu/ImagesBatter.zip?dl=0

I know this will just take you guys a little bit of time, please HELP!

Thanks!

Comment: There is no element has an ID of ball. maybe you meant to use `ball1`??

Comment: I edited your post to produce a code snippet. You can see the `null` reference error in the console when you click "Batter Up" that goes along with what guyfawkes said.

Comment: _JavaScript functions not producing expected behavior_: include the expected behavior

Comment: Note also `else..if` conditions contain single `=` operator at `else if (cycle = 200)`, `else if (cycle = 275)`

Comment: Please review how to create a [mcve]. Note that it must be in the question itself, not in a zip file on Dropbox. Use a "dummy image" service for images.

Comment: I fixed everything but it still doesn't work. the 'ball1' ; change 'else if (cycle == 200)' . Any things I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

If interpret Question correctly, `javascript` at OP passed arrays as string to functions, not element of array.

You can call `.slice()` at `runIt()` call to make copy of arrays, then reference element of copied array within functions which set `.style` using `Array.prototype.shift()`.

Note also, comparison within `if..else` assigned value, did not check for equality of values.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Batter</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      background-color: blue;
    }
    
    #ballfield {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      margin-left: 150px;
      margin-top: 10px;
      z-index: -1;
    }
    
    #ball1 {
      position: absolute;
      top: 365px;
      left: 423px;
      z-index: 2;
      visibility: visible;
    }
    
    #homerun {
      position: absolute;
      top: 200px;
      left: 150px;
      z-index: 3;
      visibility: hidden;
      height: 1px;
      width: 1px;
    }
    
    #button1 {
      position: absolute;
      left: 15px;
      top: 30px;
    }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var leftball = new Array(423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 423, 421, 419, 418, 416, 414, 413, 411, 409, 407, 406, 404, 402, 401, 399, 397, 395, 394, 392, 390, 389, 387, 385, 383, 382, 380, 378, 377, 375, 373, 371, 370, 368, 366, 365, 363, 361, 359, 358, 356, 354, 353, 351, 349, 347, 346, 344, 342, 341, 339, 337, 335, 334, 332, 330, 329, 327, 325, 323, 322, 320, 318, 317, 315, 313, 311, 310, 308, 306, 305, 303, 301, 299, 298, 296, 294, 293, 291, 289, 287, 286, 284, 282, 281, 279, 277, 275, 274, 272, 270, 269, 267, 265, 263, 262, 260, 258, 257, 255, 253, 251, 250, 248, 246, 245, 243, 241, 239, 238, 236, 234, 233, 231, 229, 227, 226, 224, 222, 221, 219, 217, 215, 214, 212, 210, 208, 207, 205, 203, 202, 200);
    var topball = new Array(365, 367, 369, 371, 373, 375, 377, 379, 381, 383, 385, 387, 389, 391, 393, 395, 397, 399, 401, 403, 405, 407, 409, 411, 413, 415, 417, 419, 421, 423, 425, 427, 429, 431, 433, 435, 437, 439, 441, 443, 445, 447, 449, 451, 453, 455, 457, 459, 461, 463, 465, 467, 469, 471, 473, 475, 477, 479, 481, 483, 485, 487, 489, 491, 493, 495, 497, 499, 501, 503, 500, 496, 492, 487, 483, 479, 475, 471, 466, 462, 458, 454, 450, 445, 441, 437, 433, 429, 425, 420, 416, 412, 408, 404, 399, 395, 391, 387, 383, 379, 374, 370, 366, 362, 358, 353, 349, 345, 341, 337, 333, 328, 324, 320, 316, 312, 307, 303, 299, 295, 291, 286, 282, 278, 274, 270, 266, 261, 257, 253, 249, 245, 240, 236, 232, 228, 224, 220, 215, 211, 207, 203, 199, 194, 190, 186, 182, 178, 173, 169, 165, 161, 157, 153, 148, 144, 140, 136, 132, 127, 123, 119, 115, 111, 107, 102, 98, 94, 90, 86, 81, 77, 73, 69, 65, 61, 56, 52, 48, 44, 40, 35, 31, 27, 23, 19, 14, 10, 6, 2, -2, -6, -11, -15, -19, -23, -27, -32, -36, -40);
    var widthsize = new Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 9, 17, 25, 33, 41, 49, 57, 65, 73, 81, 89, 97, 105, 113, 121, 129, 137, 145, 153, 161, 169, 177, 185, 193, 201, 209, 217, 225, 233, 241, 249, 257, 265, 273, 281, 289, 297, 305, 313, 321, 329, 337, 345, 353, 361, 369, 377, 385, 393, 401, 409, 417, 425, 433, 441, 449, 457, 465, 473, 481, 489, 497, 505, 512, 520, 528, 536, 544, 552, 560, 568, 576, 584, 592, 600);
    var heightsize = new Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 6, 9, 11, 14, 17, 19, 22, 25, 27, 30, 32, 35, 38, 40, 43, 46, 48, 51, 54, 56, 59, 62, 64, 67, 70, 72, 75, 78, 80, 83, 86, 88, 91, 94, 96, 99, 101, 104, 107, 109, 112, 115, 117, 120, 123, 125, 128, 131, 133, 136, 139, 141, 144, 147, 149, 152, 155, 157, 160, 163, 165, 168, 170, 173, 176, 178, 181, 184, 186, 189, 192, 194, 197, 200);
    var _leftball, _topball, _widthsize, _heightsize;
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    var timer;
    var cycle = 0;

    function moveBall(a, b) {
      var x = a + document.getElementById("ball").offsetLeft;

      document.getElementById("ball").style.left = x + "px";

      var y = b + document.getElementById("ball").offsetTop;
      document.getElementById("ball").style.top = y + "px";
      console.log(x, y);
    }

    function sizeSign(a, b) {
      var x = a + document.getElementById("homerun").offsetHeight;
      document.getElementById("homerun").style.height = x + "px";

      var y = b + document.getElementById("homerun").offsetWidth;
      document.getElementById("homerun").style.width = y + "px";
    }

    function runIt() {
      if (cycle < 200) {
        moveBall(_leftball.shift(), _topball.shift())
      } else if (cycle === 200) {
        document.getElementById("ball").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("homerun").style.visibility = "visible";
      } else if (cycle < 275) {
        sizeSign(_heightsize.shift(), _widthsize.shift());
      } else if (cycle === 275) {
        clearInterval(timer);
      }
      cycle++;
    }

    function batterup() {
      if (timer) clearInterval(timer);
      _leftball = leftball.slice(0);
      _topball = topball.slice(0);
      _heightsize = heightsize.slice(0);
      _widthsize = widthsize.slice(0);
      timer = setInterval(runIt, 50);
    }
    //////////////////////////////END////////////////////////////////
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <input type="button" id="button1" value="Batter Up!" onclick="batterup()" />
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/sports/50/50/" alt="ballfield" id="ballfield" />
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/sports/50/50/" alt="baseball" id="ball" />
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/sports/50/50/" alt="home run" id="homerun" />


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Good to learn something new. But the ball go off of the page when I change runIt() and batterup().

Comment: @NhokV _"But the ball go off of the page when I change runIt() and batterup()"_ How is that related to original Question? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. What do you mean by "off the page"? How are `runIt()` and `batterup()` changed?

Comment: It run out of the baseballfield.jpg 
I just copy your function and paste!

Comment: @NhokV That is not original Question. There are several issues at `javascript` at original Question; including passing array as string instead of array element value as parameters to function calls; assigning value to variable instead of comparing values within `if..else` conditions. Have you read link at previous comment? You should be able to adjust rendering of images by adjusting values within arrays and, or image resolutions or use `css`.

Comment: I just want it look like this when I'm done:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iZEl0oL9v70
And I think I did everything the instruction said. But idk why it doesn't work.

Comment: Not sure what link is to. Consider putting forth effort in to composing Question; where the `javascript`, `html`, `css` that you have tried to solve own Question and the specific issues and expected result are included in detail within text body of Question itself. At linked plnkr the smaller image does not change position beyond the blue background image